# Qestion about vba do loop

Tags: vba, loops

I have one tricky question: Only users enter "P plus 4 random digits  "

***(eg:P1234)***into inputbox will regard as a valid code and stop runing the macro Unless it will run until a valid code has been entered. I think i almost done, but still have little problem.Here is my Code:

```
Sub asd()


Dim strcode As String
Dim strnumber As string

strcode = InputBox("what is your production code?")

Do Until strcode = InStr(1, strcode, "P",vbBinaryCompare) And Len(strcode) = 5 _ 
and strnumber = Mid(strcode, 2) and IsNumeric (strnumber)

strcode = InputBox("what is your production code?")

Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: You are correct on one thing, "I have one tricky question"; I presume the 'tricky' part is finding the question in the first place?  ;)

Comment: `Do Until Ucase(strcode) Like "P####"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use @TimWilliam's comment, and also restructure your `Do...Loop` statement code to reduce the awful clutter. Your Sub boils down to this:

```
Dim strcode As String
Do
    strcode = InputBox("what is your production code?")
Loop Until UCase(strcode) Like "P####"
```

Tip: anytime you find yourself rewriting the exact same piece of code at multiple places in a procedure, then you're probably going to regret it later. You wrote `strcode = InputBox("what is your production code?")` twice... What if you want to change the question later? You'll have to change it both places otherwise it will look strange. Better to restructure your code so that you only write any given code line once only.